# Cypress test string as HTML

Tags: testing, cypress

I have a JSON file from which HTML is extracted by a third party.

I would like to use Cypress to test the validity of the HTML within the JSON.

```js
it('Parses HTML from JSON and checks its validity', () => {
  cy
    .readFile(file)
    .then((obj) => {
      expect(obj).to.have.property('html');
      // next line is not valid
      cy.visit(obj.html);
      ...
    });
});
```

Is there a way to make Cypress treat string as a website?

Comment: Why Cypress specifically? There are lower level HTML parsing tools that would be much faster and not require the content to be served.

Comment: I test other HTML files using `cy.visit(file)` so it's for the sake of consistency.

Comment: Then don't you just need to *serve* that HTML file?

Comment: Cypress serves files via localhost, so `cy.visit('file.html')` makes perfect sense. I have other file `file.json` which holds HTML, but accessing file through `cy.visit('file.json')` doesn't make sense. I am looking for a way to parse HTML as a string from `file.json` and then serve that string in a somewhat native way for Cypress.

Comment: You need to extract the HTML from the JSON, then; use jq or something and pipe it to a file. I thought you were saying a third party extracted the HTML from the JSON *for you*.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has it's own method for [writing files](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/writefile.html) `cy.writeFile(filePath, contents, encoding)`, the file can then be accessed with `cy.visit(file)`:

```js
it('Parses HTML from JSON and checks its validity', () => {
  cy
    .readFile(file)
    .then((obj) => {
      expect(obj).to.have.property('html');
      const filePath = './test-file.html';
      cy.writeFile(filePath, obj.html, 'utf-8');
      cy.visit(obj.html);
      ...
    });
});
```

The file in the `filePath` does remain after the test is done.